# Which version of mysql client should I use?

Tags: mysql, debian, php-7, mysql-5.7

I have VPS running Debian 8.6, PHP 7.0, MySQL 5.7. PhpMyAdmin shows me I have client version libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev. I'm a bit confused about version - when I had MySQL 5.5, client was 5.5 too. Is my client correct? Do I need to upgarde to some other version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In dotdeb.org I can't see php7-mysqlnd. If you installed php7.0-mysql, should be good. Did you installed mysql-client for 5.7?

Comment: Yes.
`~$ dpkg -s mysql-client
Package: mysql-client
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: database
Installed-Size: 47
Maintainer: MySQL Release Engineering <mysql-build@oss.oracle.com>
Architecture: amd64
Source: mysql-community
Version: 5.7.17-1debian8
Depends: mysql-community-client (= 5.7.17-1debian8)`

Comment: So... in my opinion this is a normal.